# What do I need to do to delete this Azure Active Directory tenant which has passed all initial checks?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Microsoft's UI shows me that all initial checks have passed and they can delete this Azure Active Directory tenant.  Followed by the message that Microsoft is in fact unable to delete the tenant.  Anything else I can do to actually delete this?

[image]

EDIT 1
Seems I'm getting 403
[image]

I am the only user left in the tenant and have global admin.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-delete-howto#enterprise-apps-with-no-way-to-delete) it says,
We can delete the tenants (enterprise applications) which cannot be deleted in portal by using below `PowerShell` commands.

Below are the referenced steps from the above documentation,

> - Open PowerShell as an administrator.
> - Run Connect-AzAccount -tenant <TENANT_ID>.
> - Sign in to Azure AD in the Global Administrator role.
> - Run Get-AzADServicePrincipal | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $_.Id }.

For more information on this PowerShell command, see [Remove-AzureADServicePrincipal.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadserviceprincipal?view=azureadps-2.0&preserve-view=true)

And the [Troubleshoot failed service request: Error 403 (Forbidden)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/troubleshoot-error-403).

Comment: This does not work either.